# Data does not show in server explorer database after inserting new values

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I created a backup form with this code:

```
private void btnBackUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)            //Backup will work only when we place |DataDirectory| in our appconfig file
{
        try
        {
            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            progressBar1.Value = 15;
            bool bBackUpStatus = true;

            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            if (Directory.Exists(@"D:\Backup_MAConvent"))
            {
                if (File.Exists(@"D:\Backup_MAConvent\MAConvent_Backup.bak"))
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show(@"Do you want to replace it?", "Back", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        File.Delete(@"D:\Backup_MAConvent\MAConvent_Backup.bak");
                    }
                    else
                        bBackUpStatus = false;
                }
            }
            else
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\Backup_MAConvent");

            if (bBackUpStatus)
            {
                con.Open();

                progressBar1.Value = 25;

                string path1 = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"SchoolDatabase.mdf");

                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("backup database [" + path1 + @"] to disk ='D:\Backup_MAConvent\MAConvent_Backup.bak' with init,stats=10", con);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                progressBar1.Value = 35;
                con.Close();

                timer1.Start();

                MessageBox.Show("Backup of the Database saved Successfully", "Back", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                timer1.Stop();
                progressBar1.Value = 10;
                progressBar1.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Backup Error, Please close the software & restart and then try again to backup", "Backup", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

This code was not working with the connection string of `\bin` database. So, I changed my connection string in `app.config` to `|DataDirectory|`

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolManagement.Properties.Settings.SchoolDatabaseConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SchoolDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

After that, when I was inserting new values to the database, the values were temporary showing in my search form having search query. But after stopping debugging the data was not in the database.

And then I changed `Copy To output directory` to `copy if newer` . so, now the data is showing on form's search gridview every time but it is not showing in the server explorer's database(show table data).

I know this problem is occurred due to the `|Data directory|` database and \bin database. Please suggest what to do? If I changed my connection string to the \bin database, all works well but backup code does not work. Please help if somebody knows the way to sort out this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `SchoolDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SchoolDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.

Comment: I have SSMS Express 2008 installed already and Attach database is not working with Visual Studio 2012 database, it shows incompatible error in attaching. one more thing that the above backup code is not working for the SSMS Express database(I used this in my previous project instead of service base databe). That's why I choose visual studio,s service base database in this project.