# SQL Table isn't updating but my datagridview1 is being populated during runtime with information from textboxes

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am trying to develop an inventory Windows Forms app with C# and local SQL Server. Somehow my dataGridView1 is taking information from the local SQL Server table and I even managed to populate the dataGridView1 with information from textboxes but whenever I want to check the SQL Server table after existing the app, when I go Server Explorer -> Invetory.mdf -> Right Click "Show Data Table" there is no information stored and when I click the refresh button, everything that was stored during runtime and after multiple re-initialization...just disappeared.

I even restarted my computer and the information is saved in dataGridView1 when re-launching, but the SQL Server table is still empty.

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
        SqlConnection connectionsql;
        string  connectionString;

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Equipment_Inventory.Properties.Settings.InventoryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        }

        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            populategrid();
        }

        private void populategrid()
        {
            using (connectionsql = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Inventory", connectionsql))
            {
                DataTable InventoryTable = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(InventoryTable);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = InventoryTable;
            }
        }

        private void insert_button(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "insert into Inventory (InternalNumber, Grupa, Type, Manufacturer, Equipment) values (@InternalNumber, @Grupa, @Type, @Manufacturer, @Equipment)";

            using (connectionsql = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connectionsql))
            {
                connectionsql.Open();
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@InternalNumber", textBox1.Text);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Grupa", textBox2.Text);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Type", textBox3.Text);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Manufacturer", textBox4.Text);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Equipment", textBox5.Text);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                populategrid();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of my datagridview1 at runtime:

[image]

Screenshot of my local SQL Server table:

[image]

I am sad that in other Youtube videos, with codes just like this the SQL table is updating. It's not Local SQL but still...

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: I can't quite understand what's happening from your description, but perhaps you are looking at the wrong MDF file. Especially if you're seeing loaded data in your app but not in the MDF

Comment: That's what baffles me the most, that the datagriedview1 is being populated and ONLY when I click refresh to check the Table in the ONE AND ONLY inventory.mdf file that I have on my computer...everything disappears...

Comment: Maybe the  command.ExecuteNonQuery(); doesn't increment? How can I check that?

Comment: I reread your question. It sounds like data is never stored in your database. When you restart your code, no data is found. When you refresh your grid, no data is found. You need to put a breakpoint on `insert_button` and see what it does.

Comment: Yes, my data is never stored in my local SQL **Table** database but it is so strange because when I click the function **insert_button** you can clearly see that I am calling **populategrid();** which takes objects from the SQL Table database. Maybe [this](https://streamable.com/6v1dox) can explain my problem better. It's a streamable link.

Comment: A similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733131/data-does-not-show-in-server-explorer-database-after-inserting-new-values

Comment: I don't have much experience with this framework, my best guess is that the IDE is recreating the table in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely connecting to some other test table or any other same database schema you made on your local system.
To verify that you are targeting this table, you need to insert some rows manually and check here in your form either the rows are loading in datagridview1 or not.
After that you will target the issue. There nothing looking wrong in your code.

Comment: I only have one SQL database on my PC and I tested this on another system and it gives me the save error, so it's something in my code. Can you please check this [video link](https://streamable.com/s4fckw). It's interesting that now it's incrementing from 1003? Please, help me :(

Comment: @i33SoDA I see that not only the entries are not saved, but also the id counters get reset, as if the database got recreated/reset. Are you sure those "refresh" buttons you are pressing on the IDE's GUI do actually refresh and not "reset database" or something?

Comment: Another observation: the row inserted manually from the IDE survived the "refresh" and it was shown in the datagridview when you run the program, while the ones inserted by the program dissapeared.  I suspect the "CREATE table" sql command gets reexecuted somehow...

Comment: Why dont you try to add some rows from our side of the code. and then check either your datagrid is loading all the rows ? If yes then something is wrong in your insert code.

Comment: Thanks to @RobertLee I found the problem. Apparently when I am hitting "Start" the program is creating another .mdf file ( a duplicate from the original .mdf file ) which is updating during runtime in the "Debug" folder while the original .mdf file which is inside the project's main folder is not updating. That why if I manually connect to the database and insert some objects at runtime the program will see those inserted objects and then will start working only with the .mdf file which is inside "Debug" folder. Thanks again.